# Alternative of ControlSend() function of AutoIT in Perl

Tags: perl, autoit

ControlSend() works in a similar way to Send() but it can send key strokes directly to a window/control, rather than just to the active window. It takes the window/control hwnd as a parameter with keystrokes.
I have used

```
SendMessage($_,WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
SendMessage($_,WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

and

```
SendMessage($Ctrls5,WM_CHAR, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

I have also used SendKeys("{ENTER}"); but it wants the window to be present in foreground.

Help me in solving this.

Comment: How is this relevant to Perl?

Comment: I want to know is there any function in perl which performs the similar function as ControlSend() in Autoit. So from it i can send keystrokes to the window in background using perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the Enter key for carriage return in text box then you have no function for that.

But if you want to send enter key on a button or any other control(to click on it) then you can do so by the function

**PushChildById(Parent_HWND ,ctrl_Hwnd);**

**PushChildButton(Parent_HWND , Ctrl_regex);**